# oop principles(single responsibility, inappropriate intimacy, indecent exposure): struggling with a concrete example

Tags: python, oop

I am playing around a little with Neuroevolution in Python. I am having a hard time applying some oop principles like single responsibility (any class should only have one clearly defined responsibility), inappropriate intimacy (classes should know as little as possible about each other) or indecent exposure (you should change class internals as little as possible from the outside).

I mainly read the "[Code Smells](https://blog.codinghorror.com/code-smells/)" article on codinghorror about those issues.

Here is my concrete problem:
I want to evolve a Population of Genomes over time. Genomes are an encoding of nodes and connections that can then be used to create a Neural Network. Genomes can evolve over time via mutations (e.g. mutating the weights or adding new nodes and/or connections). The aim is to steer the evolution such that the fittest Genomes in every generation are kept and the others pruned away. Fitness is determined by a cost function that can be defined beforehand. I want the Fitness Evaluation part to be as generic as possible such that I can use my code for different problems (e.g. solving XOR or solving a simple maze).

Currently I am thinking of having the following classes:

- `Population`: has a certain amount of Genomes, provides methods to advance the entire population to the next generation
- `Genome`: has Nodes and Connections, provides methods for adding and removing nodes/connections
- `MutationGenome`: inherits from Genome and provides additional functionality for all the possible mutations that can happen
- `Network`: is the Neural Network representation of a Genome, provides methods such as calculating the outputs based on given inputs or piping the Network to graphviz in order to create a graphical representation
- `Evaluation`: has the cost function, it e.g. compares the calculated outputs of a Network with the expected ground truth data to calculate a fitness

My problem is now mainly that both `Network` and `Evaluation` operate on the data stored in a single `Genome`. Currently I have both of them (`Network` and `Evaluation`) as singleton objects that are instantiated once in the beginning and then they can be set with a particular `Genome` and used to calculate its outputs or fitness.

However, that feels very "smelly" because I am exposing a lot of the `Genome` class in order to do those operations inside `Network` and `Evaluation`. Also I am therefore copying around a lot of `Genomes` all the time.

On the other hand I don't want the calculation or evaluation to be a part of `Genome` either, because that would really blow up the class and (imho) violate the single responsibility principle. In my eyes `Genome` is simply an encoding of the Neural Network.

Does anyone have any tips on how to proceed? I want the `Genomes` to be copied around and exposed as little as possible, on the other hand I need to perform operations on them which I don't want to be a part of the `Genome` class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just an idea: maybe you slice up your `Genome` class into several interfaces; and then you only give that interface to `Network` / `Evaluation` that each one needs to do its job. Besides, why are the last two singletons?

Comment: How would you do that practically? The way I understand an interface is you basically define what kind of methods/variables the implementing class needs to have? The problem is that e.g. the `Network` needs almost all the information in a `Genome`, i.e. all nodes and connections, in order to perform its job. They kind of operate on the same data but provide different methods for that data.

`Network` and `Evaluation` are singletons because I e.g. only want one `Evaluation` instance. Inside `Evaluation` there might be a lot of truth data defined which I don't want more than one instance of.

Comment: Just thinking: maybe you want to look into the visitor pattern here. It is hard to come up with good concrete ideas ... without a single line of code to look at. I think: if you want more specific answers ... then you will have to put up some code; and put down a more specific question.

Comment: Okay I'll do that. Thanks for the suggestion.